# New text files are created with uppercase extensions

Tags: windows-7, context-menu, file-extension

Whenever I want to create a new text file using Windows 7 Explorer’s *New ⇨ Text File* context-menu entry, I get a file with an uppercase extension. For example instead of `New Text Document.txt`, I get `New Text Document.TXT`.

I searched `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` and found a key named `.TXT`. I renamed it to `.txt` and after rebooting, it works as expected. Unfortunately, after a while, it started happening again.

Comment: You may use regmon or procmon tool from SysInternals family to find out which process is modifying this registry key, this will give you some clues to the reason of the problem.

Comment: @Jack Shainsky Thanks. How do I use it? I set up a filter like this: Path contains HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT then Include. Will this be sufficient?

Comment: regmon uses a shortcut for HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, so you should set the filter for HKCR. I would set it for HKCR\.txt for getting only the messages that you're interested in.

Comment: I have this as well, do you happen to use Notepad++?

Comment: @Qosmo No, I don't have it installed and I think I didn't install it ever on the machine I'm having trouble with.

Comment: You indicated that the problem returns after a while. Do you mean that `HKCR\.txt` gets changed back to `HKCR\.TXT` or *just* the symptom (i.e., it is still `\.txt`, but new files have uppercase extensions)? Did you try monitor register writes?

Comment: @Synetech It's been a while, but I think it was just the symptom.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

- Open the registry editor (*Start* ⇨ `regedit`)
- Navigate to the key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.TXT`
- Select *File ⇨ Export* and save it to a `.reg` file
- Open the `.reg` file in a text-editor (e.g., Notepad)
- Perform a search-and-replace to replace all instances of `.TXT` to `.txt`
- Save
- In regedit, delete the key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.TXT`
- Double-click the `.reg` file and select `[Yes]` to import/merge it
- Reboot