# New text files created with uppercase extensions

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New text files are created with uppercase extensions](https://superuser.com/questions/279434/new-text-files-are-created-with-uppercase-extensions)

New text files that are created via Explorer’s *New ⇨ Text Document* context-menu entry have uppercase extensions.

I searched my registry for `TXT` (*match whole*) and found nothing special. Could Notepad++ have changed this?

I am running Windows 7 64-bit and use Office 2003 and Notepad++.

How can I get lowercase extensions again?

Comment: @Bob, `May 5 '11 < Feb 11 '12`. nixdagibts’ issue is a subset of Torsten’s problem and would be solved with most of the same steps.

Comment: @Synetech Ah, sorry. Misread 11 (without the apostrophe) as 2011. Yea, you're right.

Comment: I know; the timestamps here can be annoying. I find the over-simplifications like dropping the current year or using “today”, “yesterday”, “five hours ago”, etc. to be irritating like what [people complain about Microsoft doing with Windows](http://superuser.com/questions/91287/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider trying `.TXT`, because extensions are stored with a preceding dot in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`.

Comment: Ah very dumb by me. you are right. Now got 2 hits, deletet them, system recreates them, everything works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

- Open the registry editor (*Start* ⇨ `regedit`)
- Navigate to the key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.TXT`
- Select *File ⇨ Export* and save it to a `.reg` file
- Open the `.reg` file in a text-editor (e.g., Notepad)
- Perform a search-and-replace to replace all instances of `.TXT` to `.txt`
- Save
- In regedit, delete the key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.TXT`
- Double-click the `.reg` file and select `[Yes]` to import/merge it
- Reboot

Comment: +1 Thats a good solution too. Especially if .TXT occurs very often