# Changing default names for new files created via the explorer context menu

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

So we have prank wars going on in the IT department and I'd like to do something original because turning people's screens upside down, hiding icons and hooking up USB ports to the reset button is getting old.

I remembered that I used to have a problem where new text documents would be created with the extension in caps.

I found the solution here: [New text files are created with uppercase extensions](https://superuser.com/questions/279434/new-text-files-are-created-with-uppercase-extensions)

So now I'd like to reverse the process and change the default names to something funny. Alas, I can't figure out how to do it. I remember that using ALZip used to cause exactly that with new folder names — they were named after birds (“Phoenix”, “Sparrow”, “Eagle”, “Crow”…).

I don't feel like installing ALZip everywhere.

We're running Win7 Enterprise x86.

Any ideas?

Comment: So do you want the system to think of .txt files as .somefunnyextension files? As in, a text editor will be able to open text files, windows will treat it as a text file, etc...

Comment: Oh, man, this is even eviller :D I originally thought of “funny name.txt”, but this way, if I hide extensions, they won't find out until they actually send the files to someone :D

Comment: have you found the way?